# Is there a command line tool to show git status in realtime?

Tags: git, command-line

I know there's git gui's like sourcetree and github for desktop, but I'm wondering if there's anything available that I could use from the command line to "watch" for changes and show the status of git files. If I were to modify a file, it would change the status of it without having to run `git status`.

Comment: watch Linux Command can help you alot...
For example,  watch -n 2 git status

Comment: `watch 'git status' ` ?

Comment: Make it `watch git status -s` to reduce the boilerplate text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As said in the comments, you can simply use the `watch` command if you're on Linux, like this:

```sh
watch git status
```

From the man page:

> **watch**  runs  command  repeatedly, displaying its output and errors (the first screenfull).  This allows you to watch the program output change over time.  By default, the program is run every 2 seconds and runs until interrupted.

In case you're on a Mac, you won't have `watch` by default, but you can install it through Homebrew like so:

```sh
brew install watch
```

Comment: one issue with this is that even though status is a read-only command, it is still blocking, so a `git pull` or any other command can fail if it's run at the same time as `git status`

Answer (score 3):

Keep a terminal open in the background with this command running:

```
while :; do clear;date;git status; sleep 1; done
```

Even better, have a separate tmux pane dedicated to just showing this output.

This way, you can at-a-glace see the realtime status of the repo in the directory where this command was invoked.